# Return code of DeleteAsync -- Xamarin with Azure

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I need to know the function / method to retrieve the return code to remove data of Azure DataBase (I use DeleteAsync), so that in case of error or NO-OK show me a screen with error. I need the same with different operations (Insert, update ...)

Next step show my code ...

```
     void delete_click_button(object sender, EventArgs a)
     {
         if (ID != "")
         {
             App.AzureService.Delete(ID);
             **//If return correct code....{**

                 DisplayAlert("Warning", "Delete satisfactory", "Back");
                 Navigation.PopAsync();
             **}
             //If return code error when delete....
             {
                //display message
             }**
         }
```

Thanks, I hope answer :D

Comment: Delete is Idempotent, if you encouter a server error return 500, If these delete is sucessful return 200, If the resource does not exist, (Depending who you ask) return 200;

Comment: How do I know if it returns 500, 200..? I dnot know how to see what return...

Comment: You don't need to return error code from your controller. You should have a service that handles errors and return a code based on the error. If everything works generally you return a 200.  Go research error codes

Comment: mmmm.. I'm sorry but don't understand you...Can you explain me a example in my code?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I assumed that you are using azure mobile apps as your mobile backend. For C# mobile app backend, the delete action under the TableController would be defined as follows by default:

```html
//DELETE tables/TodoItem/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
public Task DeleteTodoItem(string id)
{
  return DeleteAsync(id);
}
```

For you mobile client, you could invoke the delete operation as follows:

```
//delete a item and return nothing
await onlineTodoTable.DeleteAsync(new TodoItem() {Id= "bb29f1655fb94897a3074f8e5b91b86d"});

Or

//delete a item and return a JToken
JObject obj = new JObject();
obj.Add("id", "faa9a47e57114988b0395a4c32b7d05d");
var jtoken=await onlineTodoTable.DeleteAsync(obj);
```

For deleting a item and return custom response, you could change the action as follows:

```
//DELETE tables/TodoItem/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
public async Task<string> DeleteTodoItem(string id)
{
    await DeleteAsync(id);
    return id;
}
```

As I known, the `Insert`,`Update` operations would return the related values after the action executes successfully. And mobile client operations against your mobile backend would throw a exception when the request failed. I recommend that you could just wrap your mobile client operations with [try-catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch) and handle the exception (e.g log the error message or alert the client user) when calling CRUD operations against your mobile app backend instead of retrieving the http status code.